# Datepicker é mostrado por de trás do modal bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Tenho um modal em bootstrap:

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Agendar reunião do evento <?php echo $row- >denominacao; ?></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-body">
        <?php echo form_open('utilizador/alterarAgendamento'); ?>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
              <label>Data</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row->idevento; ?>" name="idevento" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control data_inserir" readonly="readonly" name="data" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 bootstrap-timepicker">
              <label>Hora</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" name="hora" />
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
              <label>Notas</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="nota" placeholder=""> </textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="form-control">Re-Agendar</button>
          <?php echo form_close(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

O input com a class `data_inserir` está a chamar a função dataPicker, mas esta aparece por trás do modal e não estou a conseguir fazer com que fique à frente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Isso normalmente é um problema com o `z-index`, tente adicionar um valor de `z-index` mais alto na sua class de exibição do DatePicker como por exemplo:

```
.suaClassDatePicker {
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

Comment: já tentei, até ja alterei o código do .js com a versão que diz que está corrigida mas não funciona :/

Comment: Qual datepicker voce está usando ? O do jquery-ui?

Comment: olá, é este, https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: @LaranjaMecânica, amigo de um olhada nesse [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/93eTU/1795/), nele eu estou forçando o z-index. Se por acaso não funcionar na sua aplicação, sugiro atualizar a biblioteca para versão mais nova. teste e me de um feedback aqui :)

Comment: Brunno, Obrigado, com o .datePicker não funcionou, mas alterei no css .datepicker.dropdown-menu {z-index:1000;} para  .datepicker.dropdown-menu {z-index:10000;} e já funcionou obrigado

Comment: @LaranjaMecânica, legal qualquer coisa é só chamar :)